# Query records that happen during a time interval

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I'm new to SQL and need some help with a query that would determine on each [1] day, [2] the car maker, and [3] count of positive test results for cars that have at least one positive test result occurring during any 15 minute window on a given day.

The data looks like:

```
date (11/12/2018)
time (8:21 AM)
car_marker (Honda, Ford, Toyota)
test_result (positive, negative)
```

My desired output would look like:

```
11/14/2018, Honda, 3 positives
12/03/2018, Ford, 5 positives
```

I'm querying this in MySQL. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can use `lag()`:

```
select date, car_maker, count(*)
from (select t*, lag(time) over (partition by car_maker, date order by time) as prev_time
      from t
      where test_result = 'positive'
     ) t
where prev_time > time - interval 15 minute
group by date, car_maker;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! How does the interval function work here? Based on the link below, it returns an integer based on the value of a position that's larger than the one you're comparing https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_interval

Comment: @Cle423t . . . Intervals are values used in date/time arithmetic.  The documentation actually does not do a good job explaining this, but the tutorial does (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/).  Why would this answer be downvoted?